# Netlogo High performance Computing

Tags: netlogo

Are there any high performance computing facilites available for running NetLogo behavior space like R servers.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [headless mode](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html#advanced) to run batches of experiments on a cluster/cloud computing platform. This involves simply running an executable so should be compatible with most setups. If you don't have access to a cluster through an institution, I know people use [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) and [Google compute](https://cloud.google.com/compute/). You probably want an instance with many cores, since that allows a single instance of BehaviorSpace to automatically distribute the runs involved in an experiment across multiple processes. Higher processing power of course helps too. You shouldn't need much memory. The n1-highcpu-16 or n1-standard-16 instance types in Google compute looks pretty ideal to me.

Comment: Also: http://www.openmole.org, http://mass.aitia.ai/index.php/intro/meme, [RepastHPC/ReLogo](http://repast.sourceforge.net/docs.php)

Comment: @Bryan Head does one simply fire a job and except the behaviourspace headless to use maximum cores available or otherwise specify it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28409720/running-netlogo-on-hpc-machine

Comment: If you don't specify the number of threads, NetLogo will attempt to detect the numbers of cores and run with that number of threads. If for some reason this doesn't work or you want run with fewer threads than you have cores, you can use `--threads`.

Comment: @BryanHead Thanks! I have tried using google compute but the cpus they offer in the trial version are only 2 cores which is not enough for the needs. It possible to use hadoop in google compute and scale the processing across multiple cpus http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420213/running-netlogo-through-instance-group-in-google-compute

Comment: I should note that before trying all these complicated solutions, you should make sure your code is optimized.