# Running NetLogo on HPC machine: how to specify the number of cores to be used?

Tags: netlogo, hpc

```
 $ wget https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/5.1.0/netlogo-5.1.0.tar.gz
 $ tar -xzf netlogo-5.1.0.tar.gz

$ ~/netlogo-5.1.0/netlogo-headless.sh \
--model ~/myproject/MyModel.nlogo \
--experiment MyExperiment \
--table ~/myproject/MyNewOutputData.csv
```

Using the above commands to run a netlogo headless on HPC machine. The problem is how to I specify the number of cores to be used or does by default take the maximum avialable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A look at http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/5.1.0/docs/behaviorspace.html#advanced reveals:

> `--threads <number>`: use this many threads to do model runs in parallel, or 1 to disable parallel runs. defaults to one thread per processor.

This is equivalent to the same setting in the BehaviorSpace GUI.

Comment: I am unaware of this, are you saying that one can run more than one simulation on single processor?

Comment: Yes, but you'll multiply memory usage accordingly, and you won't normally get any additional speedup (except perhaps under unusual circumstances, e.g., if the runs are often blocked waiting for I/O).

Comment: The question to how to specify the number of cores in the headless, using gui it is easy to do so. But how to do so in headless mode?

Comment: Oh sorry I get it.  I thought you were specifying just the threads to run on a single processor. Thanks!

Comment: If one has 8 processors and specifies it the thread count as nine. Will it run on 9 threads or 8?

Comment: 9 threads, but as Seth points out, you won't get a speed up. In fact, it'll probably run slower, since the cores will have to keep switching contexts.